# Дождаться пока предыдущая подписка закончится

Tags: angular, rxjs

Есть подписка:

```
this.documentChange.asObservable().subscribe(value => {
  if (this.autosave) {
    value._id = this.documentId;
    this.updateDocument(value, change);
  }
});
```

Работает она так: `this.documentChange.next(value)` После этого возможно еще одно срабатывание  `this.documentChange.next(value)`.

Вопрос: Как можно сделать, чтобы последнее срабатывание ждало окончание предыдущего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть подписка ... Работает она так: `this.documentChange.next(value)`

`next` это не работа подписки, а генерация событий.

> чтобы последнее срабатывание ждало окончание предыдущего

Нет такого понятий как "срабатывание"  , используйте просто термин "событие".

Я предположу, что `updateDocument` это какая-то асинхронная операция и вы хотите, чтобы обработка запросов обновления документа шло последовательно, а не параллельно.

Для этого используется оператор `concatMap`, который под капотом создает очередь:

```
this.documentChange.asObservable().pipe(
  filter(() => this.autosave),
  concatMap((value) => {
    value._id = this.documentId;
    return this.updateDocument(value, change);
  })
).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Документ обновлен');
});
```

Также у вас нет никакой отписки от потока, что приведет к утечке памяти, когда Angular попытается зарелизить ресурсы компонента:

```
private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

После `concatMap` добавьте оператор `takeUntil`:

```
takeUntil(this.destroy$)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Просто не внимательно прочитал... Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Если не сложно можете пояснить по поводу destroy$, в чем там суть?

Comment: если ответ вам помог - пометьте его галочкой, либо если будут вопросы - лучше сразу задавайте, про дестрой щас расскажу в комментарии ниже

Comment: `destroy$` это просто генератор событий, который сгенерирует ОДНО событие в методе `ngOnDestroy`, когда ваш компонент будет уничтожаться. Оператор `takeUntil` параметром принимает генератор, подписывается на него и ждет генерация события 1 раз, когда мы вызываем `destroy$.next()`  - `takeUntil` получает событие и автоматически отписывается от потока `documentChange.asObservable()` - все ресурсы релизятся, утечек нету, вуаля